# How do I set grub2 to boot last selected os on uefi system ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I just built a uefi system. I guess what I need to know does uefi have anything to do with this, and
if it does is there a different way to set last OS. If it does not matter then I have a different problem. I have installed Ubuntu twice. I have done what I know to do and it is not working.

Comment: I think this is a X-Y problem. You're asking about what you think is a solution and not about the problem itself. Now please edit your question and explain what isn't working.

Comment: There is UEFI and its settings of default boot. And grub settings on its default boot. And updates to any operating systems boot loader, typically makes it first in boot order. Or you often have to manage what you want to boot by default and easiest way to change to alternative system. Some vendor's UEFI also syncs with Windows BCD changing boot order which then requires other work arounds or just manually selecting second choice all the time.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI has nothing to do with this. Edit grub correctly and it works.